# Shortcodes not working in custom page

Tags: shortcode, archive-template

I have a plugin installed which provides shortcodes I regularly use on the site. But the shortcode is not working on custom page template.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add some informations, like your custom template code :)

Comment: Are you using the shortcode within a Loop - i.e. within `the_content()` - so all the regular content filters are applied?